# How to remove the # (hash) from the URL in intra page linking?

Tags: jquery, url, hyperlink, jquery-mobile

In jquery mobile I m using

```
$('#somebutton').click(function () {
    $.mobile.changePage("#searchResult", "slide");
});
```

to change to another page. This #searchResult is getting added in the URL I don't want that to happen .... So how do I remove that from URL.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what happens if you add "location.hash = '';"?

Comment: have you tried `location.hash = "";` on page load?

Comment: @Joseph : if I specify location.hash = ""; like this then the page returns back to parent page I wanna stay in the searchResult page itself.

Comment: I have found the solution myself 

    $.mobile.changePage("#details", {
     transition: "slide",
     reverse: false,
     changeHash: false
    });

We just have to set changeHash and reverse parameter as false.
Anyway thanks for the answers @Aaron Joseph.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
$('#somebutton').click(function () {
    $.mobile.changePage("#searchResult", {changeHash:false});
});
```

from the [JQM documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/methods.html)

Comment: Is there any way to do this for every click on a link, other than $('a').... ? You know, a configurable jquerymobile option or something? I couldn't find anything, but your solution certainly works.